# Why Cassandra cql query with hexadecimal literal works but textAsBinary does not?

Tags: java, cassandra, hex, cql, literals

I can do cassandra cql queries using hexadecimal literal, but when I try to use textAsBlob it does not work

For example the following works just fine:

```
cqlsh:sprich> SELECT * FROM "STOCK_CHECK_RTAM_ITEM_INDEX" WHERE key in (0x3631313230);

 key          | column1        | value

--------------+----------------+------------------------------------

0x3631313230 | 0x000330303100 | 0xf77374b5eced11e3a877005056b37d30

 0x3631313230 | 0x000330303200 | 0xf7757084eced11e3a877005056b37d30

 0x3631313230 | 0x000330303400 | 0xf7712ac8eced11e3a877005056b37d30
```

But the following two queries do not:

```
cqlsh:sprich> SELECT * FROM "STOCK_CHECK_RTAM_ITEM_INDEX" WHERE key in (textAsBlob("0x3631313230"));

Bad Request: line 1:84 missing EOF at ')'
text could not be lexed at line 1, char 15

cqlsh:sprich> SELECT * FROM "STOCK_CHECK_RTAM_ITEM_INDEX" WHERE key in (textAsBlob("3631313230"));
Bad Request: line 1:82 missing EOF at ')'
text could not be lexed at line 1, char 15
```

The following two queries do not give a syntax error but do not return the proper results as well:

```
cqlsh:sprich> SELECT * FROM "STOCK_CHECK_RTAM_ITEM_INDEX" WHERE key in (textAsBlob('0x3631313230'));

cqlsh:sprich> SELECT * FROM "STOCK_CHECK_RTAM_ITEM_INDEX" WHERE key in (textAsBlob('3631313230'));
```

Why is textAsBlob is not working? What mistake am I making in the proper use of textAsBlob?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra represents a blob data type as a hexadecimal number, such as `0x3631313230`.

This is different than a text data type (which is enclosed in single quotation marks), such as `'0x3631313230'`.

For those reasons, in your statements:

- `textAsBlob` doesn't work because it expects a string in single quotation marks.
- When you do use single quotation marks, since `0x3631313230` is different than  `'0x3631313230'`, it doesn't return the correct results.

You can see it clearly in the following example. Assume:

```
CREATE TABLE test(b blob, t text, PRIMARY KEY(b));
```

Now execute the following INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO test(b,t) VALUES(0x3631313230, blobAsText(0x3631313230));
```

When you do a SELECT, something like this will be returned:

```
b             |  t  
0x3631313230  |  61120
```

As you can see, `0x3631313230` is not equivalent to `'0x3631313230'`, and that's why you should use your first query to get the correct results:

```
SELECT * FROM "STOCK_CHECK_RTAM_ITEM_INDEX" WHERE key in (0x3631313230);
```

Here's the reference:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html